# Tomcat 7 interreptedExcepption

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat

trying to deploy a war file generating by spring-boot/maven project I get this log error  have someone any idea on it.

stacktrace here :

```
  classes started by g688614 in D:\dev\apache-tomcat-7.0.64\bin) 2017-12-04 18:06:18:331 DEBUG c.i.Application.logStarting : 


    Running with Spring Boot v1.5.3.RELEASE, Spring v4.3.8.RELEASE 2017-12-04 `18:06:18:331 INFO` 
    c.i.Application.logStartupProfileInfo : The following profiles are active: dev dΘc. 04, 2017 6:06:23 PM 

    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause INFOS: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"] dΘc. 04, 2017 6:06:23 PM 

    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause INFOS: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"] dΘc. 04, 2017 6:06:23 PM 

org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal INFOS: ArrΩt du service Catalina dΘc. 04, 2017 6:06:23 PM 

    org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWARs GRAVE: Error waiting for multi-thread deployment of WAR files to complete 

    java.lang.InterruptedException at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.awaitDone(FutureTask.java:404) at 

    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191) at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(

    HostConfig.java:830) at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:493) at 

    org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1704) at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(
    HostConfig.java:333) at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117) at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90) at 
    org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1373) at 

    org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1545) at 

    org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1555) at 

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1523) at java.lang.Thread.run(


    Thread.java:745)
```

thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Use a lower version of tomcat possibly 7.0.28.
The lower version keeps all war related issues resolved.
If the problem still does not solve. Then try to reconfigure tomact.